# Kafka in distributed system

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to kafka , i am running kafka in a single machine as of now. I want to run kafka in an distributed environment on multiple machines. There is no proper documentation for this. Any documentation or suggestion on this will be really helpful.

Comment: Are you thinking about [something like this](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#distributionimpl)?

Comment: I want producer to run in a different system, brokers on multiple systems and a consumer on different system to consume it.

Comment: running producer/consumer in a standalone machine won't give you much benefit. You should aim to distribute your application across cluster to balance the load and increase throughput.For example In case of producers, while running in Asynchronous  mode the level of parallelism depends on the number of brokers present in the cluster.

Comment: I am interested in doing the same, but i did not find any proper documentation for that.I want to run individual component on separate machine. Can you tell me how to configure this or is this documented some where ?

Answer (score 4):

Adding on to the previous answer by user2720864

Let us assume that Kafka system with below configuration is needed.

7 Kafka nodes

3 Zoo keepers

To achieve this install 7 Kafka instances, in 7 different server/vm(instances), and in each of these instances set a different broker-id, this will let the zookeeper identify the different kafka nodes for bookkeeping, maintenance.
broker.id=X (/config/server.properties)

To start zookeepers, you can use 3 of the previous kafka instances or can use new servers to start zookeepers. Once the servers on which zookeepers run are decided, change the /config/server.properties to specify zookeepers.

*zookeeper.connect=hostname1:port1,hostname2:port2*

In a distributed environment its nice to have 3 zoo keepers. While there is only one zookeeper which acts as a true master, other 2 zookeepers act as fail overs. When the master fails one of the two ZKs will take over as master.

I found this [link](http://www.infoq.com/articles/apache-kafka) to be very useful, it helped me clarify a lot of things about kafka architecture.

[This](https://kafka.apache.org/08/configuration.html) is a good reference for all the configurations on the property files in kafka.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I'll try to give a elaborated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need to do the follwing 
1) Set up kafka on all the machines 
2) Configure the `config/server1.properties` properties file to specify an unique `id` for each machines. You can do that by setting the `broker.id` properties in the config file. e.g. `broker.id=1`, `broker.id=2`. For every brokers this id should be unique. This is how every node is identified in a kafka cluster. 
3) Start kafka in all nodes

You can refer [Step 6: Setting up a multi broker cluster](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart) from their official quick start page.

Also [here](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/03/13/running-a-multi-broker-apache-kafka-cluster-on-a-single-node/) is a nice article worth taking a look